# IIS_IUSRS group is empty

Tags: iis, application-pool, http-error

I have 500.19 error when trying to host a PHP application

[image: Error]

I've tried to add the IIS_IUSRS group and permissions to it, but when I added it the site stopped working, maybe the problem is that the group is empty.
Can you tell me please what should I do?

Comment: "I've tried to add the IIS_IUSRS group and permissions to it" is the solution for this 500.19 error. "when I added it the site stopped working" is a different issue, and you should post more details about that if you want anyone to help.

Answer (score -2):

Well, not only IIS-IUSRS, you can also try giving read/write access to these accounts to the root folder of your Web application and all files/subs within:

NETWORK and NETWORK SERVICE.

Just check if the solution in [this similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12731320/web-config-cannot-read-configuration-file-due-to-insufficient-permissions) work for you.

Comment: if you think another answer works to answer a question, that's a pretty good sign that something might be a duplicate. In any case, answers should not be link-only.